# Gerrit 500 error while generating an HTTP credentials for a user

Tags: gerrit

Getting -
**An error occurred
Error 500 (Server Error): Internal server error

Endpoint: /accounts/self/password.http**

Any leads will be appreciated.

Expecting to get new HTTP credentials for the desired user.
Also, tried adding new user and generating HTTP password but that is failing to.